# i have added exported = "true" to activity which has intent-filter but still it shows this error

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-12

> Task :app:processReleaseMainManifest FAILED
> /Users/Ganesh/StudioProjects/sample/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
> Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

+Adding merger error on manifest file.
`Warning Package name 'uninitialized.application.id' used in: AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml. sample.carouselview manifest`

Comment: You should check your merged manifest for any components with `intent-filter`, but haven't set`exported` to true

Comment: @Praveen Merged manifest not showing for me, but found this error `Merging Errors: Warning Package name 'uninitialized.application.id' used in: AndroidManifest.xml, AndroidManifest.xml. sample.carouselview manifest`

Comment: Not only activities. You should also add to services, receivers, etc

Comment: I have done that @Noah

Comment: then it's your depencies. Make sure your dependencies are up-to-date

Comment: Checked all the dependencies too @Noah

Comment: There will be a Merged-manifest tab selection option at the bottom, after opening `AndroidManifest.xml`, select that and look for any component having `intent-filters` but not `exported = true`

Comment: Merged manifest not showing up, it shows "Nothing to show". @Praveen

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I Checked all manifest files in my project. I couldn't find any issues so, used a workaround by changing target sdk to `targetSdkVersion 30`.

Comment: I think you forgot to place the actual error in your post.

Comment: @neutcomp i have set exported properties to all activities, receiver and services. Still it shows same error.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue changed my targetSdk to 30 from 31 in build.gradle it worked.